# Function with no neighborhood definition in R?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We have the function $f\left ( x \right )= x$ such that $x\, \in \, \mathbb{Q}$
and it says that this function isn't defined at the neighborhood of any point. I don't understand why? I can take any point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and I know thanks to the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its complement $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ that the numbers immediately following and preceding my point $x_0$ will be in $\mathbb{Q}$. It will make for a very small $\delta$ about $x_0$ consisting of a single point but I don't see where I went wrong in my reasoning? Can someone help?

Thank you

Comment: The correct argument your text is using for this statement is this: "Every neighborhood of a point contains irrational numbers and $f$ is not defined at such points."  Your intuition says otherwise.  View the conflict as an opportunity to take your intuition about the real numbers and give it a good thrashing!  That's how all of us eventually learned to think correctly about these ideas.  Keep going back and forth until you see it absolutely clearly and it all seems transparent.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Sometimes one gets stubborn with an idea they formed and built upon things that seemed to work. Thank you for reminding me about what I should really do, it's comforting to know other people go through misconceptions while learning and don't get the right picture right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that the domain of the function is exactly $\mathbf{Q}$. Then considering this now as a function of $\mathbf{R}$ in the usual topology, any open neighborhood of a point $x \in \mathbf{Q}$ will contain irrationals, i.e. $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{Q}$. The function would not be defined at those points.

$\mathbf{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbf{R}$ does **not** imply that you can find rational numbers immediately preceding and succeeding a given rational number. In fact, you can always find an irrational number between any two rational numbers.

Comment: I never said that you could find rational numbers immediately preceding and succeeding a given rational numbers, I took $x_0$ to be irrational and said that immediately preceding and succeeding it are rational numbers. The interval going from $x_0$ - (im. predecing rational number) to x_0 + (im. succeeding rational number) is included in $\mathbb{Q}\cup \left \{ x_0 \right \}$

Comment: That also is not true. It doesn't even make sense to talk about numbers "immediately succeeding/preceding" in $\mathbf{R}$. Such a notion does not exist.